# Dependent properties in C#

Tags: c#, properties

BountyHunter has a secure line named JobLine that provides them with Prey to hunt.

The Prey can be changed at any time, either from the JobLine or changing circumstances that make the bounty hunter choose to swap targets.

How can I improve the dependent / calculated property that is being delegated from the BountyHunter to the JobLine ?

```
using Microsoft.Practices.Prism.ViewModel;

namespace TestBindings
{

    public class Prey
    {
        public Prey()
        {
        }
    }

    //Prey Provider
    public class JobLine : NotificationObject
    {
        public JobLine(Prey prey)
        {
            this.Prey = prey;
        }

        private Prey _prey;

        public Prey Prey
        {
            get { return _prey; }
            set
            {
                if (_prey != value)
                {
                    _prey = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Prey));
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public class BountyHunter : NotificationObject
    {
        public BountyHunter(JobLine jobLine)
        {
            JobLine = jobLine;
        }

        public Prey Prey
        {
            get { return JobLine.Prey; }
            private set
            {
                if (JobLine.Prey != value)
                {
                    JobLine.Prey = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Prey));
                }
            }
        }

        private JobLine _jobLine;

        public JobLine JobLine
        {
            get { return _jobLine; }
            private set
            {
                if (_jobLine != value)
                {
                    _jobLine = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(JobLine));
                    RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Prey));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Per docs, NotificationObject is obsolete: `[ObsoleteAttribute("Please use Prism.Mvvm.BindableBase")]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is there any reason why you implemented the same logic/property twice? `JobLine` already has a property called `Prey`:

> ```
> public Prey Prey
> {
>     get { return _prey; }
>     set
>     {
>         if (_prey != value)
>         {
>             _prey = value;
>             RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Prey));
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

so why does `BountyHunter` have it too if I can access `Pray` via `JobLine`?

> ```
> public Prey Prey
> {
>     get { return JobLine.Prey; }
>     private set
>     {
>         if (JobLine.Prey != value)
>         {
>             JobLine.Prey = value;
>             RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Prey));
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: I think I may have over simplified my question.

Comment: @RyanTheLeach posting simplified code is never a good idea, it always backfires. You should post your real code.

Comment: @RyanTheLeach what t3chb0t said. And now if editing your question would invalidate this answer, please mark it as accepted and post a new question instead - with as much context as possible. MCVE's are for [so], not this site. See [how to get the best value out of Code Review](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436/23788) for more information.